# Ambiguous error when calling app.UseWebSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to go through this tutorial to use web sockets in .NET Core: https://zbrad.github.io/tools/wscore/

I'm having trouble when I need to make this call in my Startup.cs class:

```
app.UseWebSockets();
```

I'm getting this error when it tries to build:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebSocketMiddlewareExtensions.UseWebSockets(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)' and 
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebSocketMiddlewareExtensions.UseWebSockets(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder)'

I don't know what the issue is at all, here are my dependencies in the project.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server": "0.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.1"
  }
```

Anyone have any clue what this weird ambiguous error is about? It references the same namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid mixing multiple versions of the same library. Usually, this can't happen as you either end up with new or old version of a library. But when the assembly name changes (i.e. as ASP.NET Core did when it went from RC1 to RC2, the assemblies where changed form `Microsoft.AspNet.*` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, then you get different package names too and it's possible to reference both which results in the error above.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server` is an outdated version for ASP.NET Core 1.0 and has since been renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets` with the 1.1 release, as you can see in the github repository.

#### [Version 1.0](https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/tree/1.0.0/src)

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Client
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server

#### [Version 1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets/tree/rel/1.1.0/src)

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets

You have two options:

1. Stay with ASP.NET Core 1.0 (i.e. if you have the requirement of using the LTS Version) and use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server` 0.1.0 and remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets`.
2. Upgrade to ASP.NET Core 1.1 and remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server`, as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets` 1.0.1 requires ASP.NET Core 1.1 (at least `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`)

Comment: I basically removed Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server from my package and the error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your cs file you are probably using two namespaces which have the same method definition